# Как правильно образовать мн. ч. для слова "договор": договорЫ или договорА?

Tags: грамматика

Если много договоров, как правильно употребить множественное число? ДоговорА или ДоговорЫ?

Answer (score 3):

В современном языке значительное количество сущ. м. р. в форме Р. п. мн. числа имеют нейтральное окончание Ы и разговорное А: инспекторы и инспекторА, теноры и тенорА, джемперы и джемперА, свитеры и свитерА.

Поэтому вряд ли можно ожидать, что в обозримом будущем "договорА" станут относиться к нейтральному стилю и будут применяться в письменной речи.

Comment: значит в описи документов правильно будет : "Договоры временного хранения имущества на 7 л.", " Договоры аренды на 10 л.", да?

Comment: Вы правы, именно так !

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: >> *Поэтому вряд ли можно ожидать, что в обозримом будущем "договорА" станут относиться к нейтральному стилю и будут применяться в письменной речи.*  Как раз очень даже можно ожидать. ПрофессорА же относятся, причем уже давно... Можно десятка два примеров подобрать, тенденция налицо.

Comment: А совсем давно, в дореволюционные времена, говорили, к примеру,  так: "ПрофЕссоры твердили, что он пойдет далеко. ПрофЕссоры! У них учился наш родня!"   Итак, форма "профЕссоры"  соответствует старой норме, а также встречается у поэтов. Также: согласно словарям только форма директорА является нормативной, хотя  ещё в начале 20 века  говорили дирЕкторы; однако сейчас  форма дирЕкторы  начинает  вновь активно использоваться. Вывод: процесс идет, но в обратную сторону.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: договор, мн. ***-ы, -ов и (разг.) -а, -ов***

### Дополнение

***Как правильно: дОговор или договОр? Как ставить ударение во множественном числе?***

Строгая литературная норма: договОр, договОры, в непринужденной устной речи допустим вариант дОговор, договорА. Приведем интересную цитату из «Словаря трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке» К. С. Горбачевича:

Сейчас ещё трудно с уверенностью сказать, станет ли со временем ударение дОговор столь же нормативным и эстетически приемлемым, как договОр. Предпосылки для этого есть. Не только часть интеллигенции, но и некоторые современные известные поэты употребляют вариант дОговор: «Но ты не пугайся. Я договор наш не нарушу, Не будет ни слез, ни вопросов, ни даже упрёка» (О. Берггольц, Ничто не вернётся...). В книге «Живой как жизнь» К. Чуковский предсказывал, что варианты дОговор, договорА станут в будущем нормой литературного языка.

Небольшое замечание: многие полагают, что вариант дОговор, договорА – нововведение последних лет. Однако указание на допустимость такого ударения в разговорной речи можно найти в изданиях полувековой давности, например в словаре-справочнике Р. И. Аванесова, С. И. Ожегова «Русское литературное произношение и ударение» (М., 1959).

Comment: а в контексте? " Договора временного хранения имущества" или "Договоры временного хранения имущества"

Comment: Правильно: договорЫ. ДоговорА носят разговорных характер.

Comment: ДоговОры, Серж.

Comment: Матвей, обратите внимание на вопрос:  автора интересует не ударение, а мн.ч.